# Suggest several apps in playstore to user (Similar to Share dialog)

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

My app forwards users to a different app to perform a specific action (e.g. ACTION_SHARE, except that the apps that I forward users to do not implement an intent filter) Since they don't implement intent filters, I have a list of package names that support the action.

This part is working fine, like this:

```
for (String knownApp : knownApps) {
    Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(knownApp);
    if (intent != null) {
        ResolveInfo resolveInfo = pm.resolveActivity(intent, 0);
        intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, knownApp, resolveInfo.loadLabel(pm), resolveInfo.icon));
    }
}
LabeledIntent[] extraIntents = intentList.toArray(new LabeledIntent[intentList.size()]);
Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(actionIntent, getString(R.string.perform_action_with));
openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
startActivity(openInChooser);
```

If the user has none of the apps installed, I want to give the user a choice of apps to download to fulfill the action.

[Currently that looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TZXu.png)

[image]

As you can see it's lacking both icon and name. For regular apps I use an intent chooser which needs LabledIntent, but on one hand, I can't get the name and icon from the playstore unless I scrape them (which is not allowed by google, besides LabledIntent requires a resourceId as the Icon, which I can't get for downloaded files.), on the other the intent chooser won't seem to display the intent unless the package name of the intent and LabeledIntent match. This does not work for URIs which I'm using to access the Play Store in the first place.

Now I'm looking for ideas on how to get the following code to display both the correct name and app icon, as well as forward to the correct page on the play store.

```
protected void showPlayStoreOptions(List<String> knownApps) {
    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent();
    Intent showIntent = Intent.createChooser(chooserIntent, "You need one of these Apps on Google Play..."); //googles brand guidelines state that "on Google Play" has to be used
    List<Intent> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String knownApp : knownApps) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + knownApp)); //normally you would try an uri with market:// first, catch the exception if no playstore is installed and then use this, but the intent chooser seems to automatically forward correctly.
        list.add(intent);
        //list.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + knownApp, "test name", R.drawable.icon_info));
        //list.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, ""+Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + knownApp), "test name", R.drawable.icon_info));
    }
    showIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, list.toArray(new Intent[list.size()]));
    startActivity(showIntent);
}
```

So to sum up my questions.

- How can I get a resource Id from a downloaded image file, or how can I use the downloaded image file with a LabledIntent.

(Extending LabledIntent does not work due to issues with parceling (and those methods are package private))

- How can I display a LabledIntent in a choose intent with an URI?

I realize it's probably easier to write my own chooser, but I want to wrangle this into the default android system.